# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (med2images package)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I use macOS. I want to run python package of med2image in a python script (Package Link: https://github.com/FNNDSC/med2image). I sucessfully installed med2image by using the following command:

```
pip3 install med2image
```

Then, I imported it in python3 but I can not use it and I get the following error:

```
>>> import med2image
>>> med2image.py -i mypicture.nii -d outputDir -o slice.jpg -s -1
File "<stdin>", line 1
med2image.py -i mypicture.nii -d outputDir -o slice.jpg -s -1
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even when I use med2image instead of med2image.py in the command line, I get the same error. What Should I do?

Comment: You put a *command line* into your Python interpreter. That's not Python code.

Comment: So, what should I do? (I want to run python package of med2image in a python script)

Comment: You'll have to see if the [script lends itself to importing](https://github.com/FNNDSC/med2image/blob/master/med2image/med2image.py).

Comment: Or rather [this is the script file](https://github.com/FNNDSC/med2image/blob/master/bin/med2image), see how it uses `med2image.med2image_*` calls, and replicate that in your own code.

Comment: How can I check if the script lends itself to importing? Also, if importing is not possible, what is the best method to run this package inside a python script?

Comment: The `bin/med2image` file I linked to is the script. It imports the module and drives it based on the command line arguments. So it does appear to lend itself to importing.

Comment: Thanks. However, as you see in my original post, I imported the module, I write my command line which is based on the instruction in the site, but I get the syntax error. what should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to do all the work for you. Read the code I linked to, figure out how the command-line arguments end up being used, replicate that.